# Quasi-synonyms for quasi-tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-excerpt

I have been reviewing our quasi-related threads, and have edited the wiki excerpt of [quasi-likelihood](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quasi-likelihood) to read:

> In GLMs, quasi-likelihood estimation is a way to allow over- or under-dispersion by choosing an appropriate variance function. It's often used for count data, e.g. in quasi-binomial or quasi-Poisson models; there it does not correspond to any actual count distribution.

I would suggest to make [quasi-binomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quasi-binomial)×13 and `[quasi-poisson]` (currently not existing) synonyms of this more general `[quasi-likelihood]` tag. I don't think we have enough threads to warrant splitting this into narrow sub-tags.

In fact, I was going to manually retag all `[quasi-binomial]` questions into `[quasi-likelihood]`+`[binomial]`, but @Glen_b suggested to raise it on Meta, and it's probably a good idea to have these synonym mappings anyway.

Comment: I have also found a bunch of questions about quasi-Poisson that did not have any quasi- tag. I tagged  a few with [quasi-likelihood]. This supports the idea of creating synonyms.

Comment: Maybe we should change the quoted excerpt by saying "It's often used for *binary or* count data" and removing "count" in the end.

Comment: I have shortened that wiki excerpt to conform with our [length policy](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2848).  BTW, manual retagging is not needed (and should be strongly discouraged because it alters the site systematically in a way that is difficult to reverse): once a synonym has been established, the system will apply it automatically.  That's one of the main points of using synonyms!

Comment: I think the link should have been to here: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2848 @whuber. I thought in this case it's important to mention quasi-binomial and quasi-poisson. But actually if we have synonyms that they will appear nearby anyway, when one is selecting a tag for a new question. Re manual retagging: I know! I thought with 15 Qs it does not really matter. But yes.

Comment: Sorry--I cut off the last digit of the question number when pasting the link.  It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both synonyms were created by @gung some time ago.